# Finding the highest COUNT of a group per individual GROUP BY query in Hive

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql

I have a table of customer transactions where an individual_id appears once for every different transaction.
There is a category column called Name_desc which i would like to group by individual and find the most common category of name_desc per individual.

Suppose data is like below

```
Id          Name_desc
----        ------
1           a
2           c
1           b
2           c
1           b
```

> I want below output

```
Id        Name_desc( most occuring category)
------    ------
1          b
2          c
```

I tried with below query and got an 
**Error while compiling statement: FAILED: ParseException line 4:19 cannot recognize input near 'select' 'max' '(' in expression specification**
error

```
select name_desc, count(*) as count_e
from db.cust_scan
group by id, name_desc
having count(*)= ( select max(count_e),id
from
(
select id, name_desc, count(*) as count_e
 from 
  db.cust_scan
        where 
        base_div_nbr =1 
        and 
        country_code ='US' 
        and
         retail_channel_code=1 
         and visit_date between '2019-01-01' and '2019-12-31'
         GROUP  by 
         individual_id, tt_id_desc
         order by individual_id, count_e desc
         ) as t 
         group by individual_id )
```

I would appreciate any suggestions or help with regard to query. If there is an efficient way of getting this job done. Let me know.

Answer (score 1):

This following script written and tested for MSSQL. But as HIVE also support the same Row_Number() ans sub query, this following query should help you getting your required output-

```
SELECT A.Id, A.Name_desc 
FROM
(
    SELECT Id,Name_desc,
    row_number() over (partition by id order by COUNT(*) desc) AS RN
    FROM your_table
    GROUP BY Id,Name_desc
) A
WHERE RN = 1
```

Comment: . . This is standard SQL and should work in any database (although I recommend using `as` for column aliases).

Answer (score 0):

You need subquery in Hive:

```
SELECT s.Id, s.Name_desc 
FROM
(
select s.*, row_number() over (partition by s.id order by s.cnt desc) rn
from
(
    SELECT Id, Name_desc, COUNT(*) cnt
    FROM your_table
    GROUP BY Id, Name_desc
) s
) s
WHERE rn= 1;
```